# arrange two sets of columns in alternating order in excel

Tags: excel, columnsorting

So, I have two sets of columns that look like this:

```
ColA1 ColA2 ColA3     ColB1 ColB2  ColB3
 0.2   0.4    0.3       55    61    55.2
```

And I want to rearrange their order so that they alternate like this:

```
ColA1 ColB1 ColA2 ColB2 ColA3  ColB3
 0.2   55    0.4    61   0.3    55.2
```

There's many rows in this sheet, and each row has a different number of columns (though they are all even numbered like this example). I can't figure out what the formula would be to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the top-left corner of your destination and fill both right and down.

```
=INDEX($G$5:$M$6, ROW(1:1), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*0.5+1+ISEVEN(COLUMN(A:A))*4)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this looks really good, thanks - but I should've been more specific in my example.  The column names are F - Y and AA - AU, how does that change your formula?